How to call a RestAPI or an internal function based on chat engine query in llama-index?
I'm new to llama-index and OpenAI. I have a requirement. I had to call a function or a Rest API in python based on the user query. Is that possible?

This question is too generic. You must provide more context, describe what you are trying to do and what is not working.
